# Battlefield 3 Stats Api

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, web-services

I'm building a web app in PHP. In the app need to pull in some stats from the game Battlefield 3 via api requests. I'm looking for a source to use for the api requests. I've looked at [bf3stats.com](http://bf3stats.com), however they recommend that I cache the results and not poll for every page request.

What I'm looking for is an api where I can poll for data a couple times a minute. Are there any such api's available? Does [EA](http://www.ea.com/)'s Blaze offer an api?

Comment: This website is more for specific questions regarding things you have tried, not a place to find out generalized info.

Comment: OP - "Do the research for me."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to figure out how to do the requests yourself.

There isn't anything out there that does that publicly yet.

Note: You shouldn't post these types of questions here. You are basically just asking us to research for you. Feel free to post questions about making the requests themselves though.

Comment: I'm not asking how to do the requests, I'm asking for an api source for the requests...if there are any available.

Comment: and i'm telling you, there isn't one publicly available, you have to do the request yourself...